# Python Selenium doesn't find chromedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to learn web scraping with Python and Selenium. However, I have been getting an error of `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'` and I am 100% sure that the file is located on the path that I specified as I tried it with much simpler approach before and everything was working fine.

This is my code right now;

```
class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"/Users/username/Desktop/SeleniumDriver/chromedriver"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ["PATH"] += r"/Users/username/Desktop/SeleniumDriver"
        super(Booking, self).__init__()

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get("https://website.com")


inst = Booking()
inst.land_first_page()
```

I have tried different many paths with/without r as prefix as well as /chromedriver with exe as an extension or without. Nothing seems to be working. I am getting the error that I mentioned above when instantiating the Booking class

Instead of using OOP if I use the webdriver like this;

```
os.environ["PATH"] += r"/Users/username/Desktop/SeleniumDriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/username/Desktop/SeleniumDriver/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://website.com")
```

It works, and doesn't give me any errors, but I would prefer to use OOP approach as it much more clear for me to work with, especially when creating bots

Comment: make sure your chromedrivers are in your path.

Comment: I would avoid using classes if I was just trying to learn how selenium works. `driver=webdriver.Chrome("r"/Users/username/Desktop/SeleniumDriver/chromedriver.exe")`  then `driver.get("https://website.com")` will work just fine

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: macOS Monterey @DebanjanB

Comment: @God-status yes, they are; please check the edited question

Comment: @West well, yes technically it would solve my issue for now but, eventually I would use OOP. Also why would it not work with OOP approach

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac/Linux, The location is okay

```
/Users/username/Desktop/SeleniumDriver/chromedriver
```

If you're using Windows, you may need to specify from the actual drive

```
C:/Users/username/Desktop/SeleniumDriver/chromedriver
```

Comment: yes, I am using Mac, and if I don't use OOP approach the path works fine but when I instantiate Booking class it gives the error

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hack by modifying this line

```py
super(Booking, self).__init__()
```

to this

```py
super(Booking, self).__init__(driver_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for the `__init__` method there is no instance variables initialised there.
By that I mean for example there is nothing like `self.driver_path = "path"`.

```
def __init__(self, executable_path="chromedriver", port=0,
                 options=None, service_args=None,
                 desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None,
                 chrome_options=None, keep_alive=True):
        """
        Creates a new instance of the chrome driver.

        Starts the service and then creates new instance of chrome driver.

        :Args:
         - executable_path - path to the executable. If the default is used it assumes the executable is in the $PATH
         - port - port you would like the service to run, if left as 0, a free port will be found.
         - options - this takes an instance of ChromeOptions
         - service_args - List of args to pass to the driver service
         - desired_capabilities - Dictionary object with non-browser specific
           capabilities only, such as "proxy" or "loggingPref".
         - service_log_path - Where to log information from the driver.
         - chrome_options - Deprecated argument for options
         - keep_alive - Whether to configure ChromeRemoteConnection to use HTTP keep-alive.
        """
        if chrome_options:
            warnings.warn('use options instead of chrome_options',
                          DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
            options = chrome_options

        if options is None:
            # desired_capabilities stays as passed in
            if desired_capabilities is None:
                desired_capabilities = self.create_options().to_capabilities()
        else:
            if desired_capabilities is None:
                desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
            else:
                desired_capabilities.update(options.to_capabilities())


        self.service = Service(
            executable_path,
            port=port,
            service_args=service_args,
            log_path=service_log_path)
        self.service.start()

        try:
            RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
                self,
                command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(
                    remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
                    keep_alive=keep_alive),
                desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
        except Exception:
            self.quit()
            raise
        self._is_remote = False

    def launch_app(self, id):
        """Launches Chrome app specified by id."""
        return self.execute("launchApp", {'id': id})

    def get_network_conditions(self):
        """
        Gets Chrome network emulation settings.

        :Returns:
            A dict. For example:

            {'latency': 4, 'download_throughput': 2, 'upload_throughput': 2,
            'offline': False}

        """
        return self.execute("getNetworkConditions")['value']
```

So in your code the line `self.driver_path = driver_path` is not doing anything. It sets an instance variable that is not used by the parent class.

You can pass the path in the super statement to make it work:

```
super().__init__(executable_path = "/Users/username/Desktop/SeleniumDriver/chromedriver")
```